# InvalidOperationException: Could not locate the hub named 'Roslyn'

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm making a Roslyn diagnostic. When debugging the diagnostic, which launches a separate instance of Visual Studio, I get the following exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   Microsoft.VsHub.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not locate the hub named 'Roslyn'

No further details are given. What does this exception mean? What can I do about it? I'm quite confused because earlier I was able to debug this project just fine. I've tried to 'git clean -f -x -d' but to no avail.

Comment: Are you breaking on first chance exception? Visual Studio throws all sorts of exceptions during startup.

Comment: Ok yeah you're right this is actually normal behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As discussed, Visual Studio throws a lot of exceptions during startup. Debugging tips are either:

1. Enable "Just My Code" under Debugging > General in Tools Options.
2. In the Exception Settings window, make sure breaking on an exception being thrown is off.